# How to check if an html element is on top of other?

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

Lets say I have a website where I have some components and main panel. The idea is to take components and add them to the main panel (like a website builder of some sort). And the question is how do I know if I have one component on top of another? *Also it would be perfect if i'd know the coverage area size*

Note: I dont like the idea of checking positions for every element on this panel. If it can be done with getters or something similar i'd be happy

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Let's say We have some rules here on SO. And those rules state that you should share the minimum amount of information in your question that would reproduce your problem. Also, they state ( among others ) that you should share what you have done to try to solve your problem. NOTE : yes, this can be done. But not here on SO. Here we help you debug your code, not make code for you for free or recommend tutorials/libraries or other.

Answer (score 0):

you can always use "inspect element" option in Google. There are so much option for developers.

and of course if you are developing something you would have an assumption about the initial position, so this is not a problem while doing.